# One table for all files or many tables with file column?

Tags: sql-server

Solution one would be having about 20 tables that could hold files in a separate column and second solution the option of having 20 tables and one extra table containing all files and have links/relationships between the file table and the other 20 tables. The files are small PDF files of about 0,5 MB. Seems safer with columns so no client could see other clients data by mistake. Columns would be varbinary MAX

Comment: My first inclination is to suggest one table containing columns `ClientID` and `FileContent` along with additional columns for file attributes and the primary key. Assuming all database access is done via the app layer against a multi-tenant database, there shouldn't be any difference in risk with a single table versus separate tables per client. Search the internet multi-tenant database for other considerations.

Comment: Don't do it at all.  Rename the file as a GUID and put the GUID in your database.  Put the file in a filesystem and if you need it served quickly use a CDN, Content Delivery Network, which is dirt cheap, super simple, and will very probably deliver the data to the client faster than your Db would've with the file(s).

Answer (score 2):

Put them all in one table, with (e.g., File table, with a File_ID as PK). Other tables refer to this as File_ID.

Why?

*SELECT * FROM OneOfTheTables*

You just *know* someone will do it from one of your tables. If it's included in each table, all those PDFs will be returned even though they're not being used.

On your dev/test server (with not much data and nobody competing for resources) it's not a big issue, but could really hurt performance on production. If it's just recorded as a foreign key (e.g., to File.File_ID) then it's not a big deal: it's still not good (they should just get the fields they want) but better than also returning an extra half a MB per row.

*Upgradable file management*

Some time in the future, you may want to store files elsewhere (e.g., local file storage, in Dropbox, in the cloud). No matter which option you choose, you'd need to write the code to deal with files that could be in different places (indeed, you may even want to move them from one location to another).

If it's all in one table (the File table) it's much easier to add a column to your table that says where it's stored. The File_ID references in the other tables won't need to change.

Indeed, you may decide to store the PDF files it in a database, but in a different one from your main application. You may even want to keep them in a database but on a separate (smaller) server that does nothing but host these files. These are all easier by keeping the Files separate.

So

- Your 20 tables have reference to the File table (e.g., File_ID).
- The File table has relevant details about the file (name, who put it here, what type of file it is, etc) and is a pointer to where it is actually stored and what type of storage it is
- Have a table to store the filestreams/etc if desired

---

**UPDATE: Proviso**

Brent Ozar did a video 10 years ago about the 'Top 10 developer mistakes that won't scale' in production.

Storing files in the database was one of them. I think he called SQL Server 'the second most expensive place to store files' (Oracle being the most expensive).

A recent review he did of that video (after 10 years) still agreed - see [the video, starting at the appopriate location](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHgWBg2iGVw&feature=youtu.be&t=2317)

Comment: This is a good response, an important discussion element to include (For SQL Server) is how you can allocate the file table to an isolated _Data File_  and the next progression FileStream Access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @seanb I have a similar question, but my tables have a 1 to many relationship with the File table.  Should I put 20 NULLABLE columns in my file table that reference each table or have a separate File table for each object?  The other option would be is to have a generic "ObjectId" column with an "ObjectType" column and not have a FK relationship to each table?

Comment: @Andrew I think that is a slightly different question - but it may be worthwhile thinking of the fields as 'just another type of data' rather than files. As such, if it is truly 1-to-many (e.g., each file is only used in one place) then you can put the relevant references in the file table e.g., File_ID, File_Contents, File_Name, and FK reference back to the table which uses the file. Otherwise, if it's many-to-many, you can make an appropriate table linking File_ID to the key of the original table.